# toeplitz Matrix for a given N

Tags: python, scipy, toeplitz

For a given N, I need to create the following matrix:
[image]

I have understood that :

```
 from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
 y=toeplitz(range(1,N))
```

will create a Toeplitz matrix. But it is not the exact matrix given above.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html):

> `scipy.linalg.toeplitz(c, r=None)`
>
> Construct a Toeplitz matrix.
>
> The Toeplitz matrix has constant diagonals, with c as its first column and r as its first row. If r is not given, r == conjugate(c) is assumed.

Thus you need to pass the first column and the first row like this:

```
toeplitz(c=[1, *np.arange(N,1,-1)], r=np.arange(1,N+1))
```